# How is occupation number of lowest unoccupied natural orbital defined?

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, radicals, density-functional-theory

I have run some calculations to analyse the occupation of natural orbitals. Since it is needed to run in triplet state, I get two orbitals with occupation number 1. Now, which orbital occupation number is to be taken as the occupation  number of lowest unoccupied natural orbital as it is needed to define the diradical character in the system ?

Comment: Why would the degeneracy in *occupied* orbitals raise any ambiguities for the *unnocupied* orbitals?

Comment: I am facing issue in defining it. The reported values and that from my calculations do not match. May be my procedure is wrong but I am not able to identify where is the fault. @Feodoran

Comment: I don't know what values you are talking about, but if you have two singly occupied orbitals (SOMO), then the LUMO should be the one next lowest in energy. For natural orbitals it probably has some occupation number slightly larger than 0. But I am not aware of any strict definition here.

Comment: thank you @Feodoran that is also my line of thought but then my diradical character values are not matching with the reported values (e.g. for polyacenes)